# Expectation calculation

Tags: probability-theory

Given that $X\in$Exp($\theta$) and that $f(y|x)=1/x$ for $0<y<x$. I want to calculate $E[Y]$.

What I tried:

$E[Y|X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty yf(y|x) dy =\frac{1}{x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y dy=0$

Then $E[Y]=E[E[Y|X]]=E[0]=0$, am I thinking right or is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x) = \theta e^{- \theta x},\ x >0$. The pdf of $Y \mid X $ is $f_{Y \mid X}(y) = \frac{1}{X},  \ 0 < y < X$.

$$
E[Y \mid X=x] = \int_0^x \frac{y}{x} \; dy  = \frac{x}{2}
$$

So $E[Y \mid X] = \frac{X}{2}$ and $E[Y] = E[ E[Y \mid X]] = E[\frac{X}{2}] = \frac{1}{2\theta}$